# store function attribute of class in QGIS plugin

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm pretty new to python and pyqgis so the question will be pretty trivial..

I'm writing a plugin and in one script I have a class and some internal functions..

```
....
class CreateModelDialog(QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, iface):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
....
    def openSr(self):
        projSelector = QgsGenericProjectionSelector()
        projSelector.exec_()
        self.srText.setText(projSelector.selectedAuthId())
```

Then I have to use the last line (that is the EPSG cose selected and displayed in `srText` QLineEdit of the QT dialog in another function of the same script:

```
def createModel(self):
        modelName = self.bxDBname.text()
        modelType = self.cmbBxModelType.currentText()
        crs = self.srText.setText(projSelector.selectedAuthId())

createModel(modelName, modelType, crs)
```

But I get an error:

```
NameError: global name 'projSelector' is not defined
```

I'm sure that is due to the fact that `projSelector` is a variable that exists only in the local `open Sr` function.

So the question is: how should I modify the function in order to make the variable callable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create instance vairiables with **self** keyword:

```
def openSr(self):
        self.projSelector = QgsGenericProjectionSelector()
        self.projSelector.exec_()
        self.srText.setText(self.projSelector.selectedAuthId())
```

Now your self.projSelector variable is ready to use in other methods.

```
dialog = CreateModelDialog(iface)
...
dialog.projSelector
```

Will return your variable with this object.

Comment: Tried with your command but it doesn't work.. I solved creating ``projSelector`` as a ``global variable``: ``global projSelector``